# How to quickly pack spheres in 3D?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm looking for an algorithm for [random close packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_close_pack) of spheres in 3D.  The trick is that I'd like to pack spheres **around** a certain number of existing spheres.  So for example, given somewhere between 100 and 1000 spheres in 3D (which have fixed positions and sizes; they may overlap, and may be different sizes), I'd like to pack  spheres (all same size, positions can be chosen freely) around them (with no overlaps).

The metric for a good quality of packing is the packing density or void fraction.   Essentially I'd like the fixed spheres and the packed spheres to occupy a compact volume of space (eg roughly ~spherical, or packed in layers around the fixed spheres) with as few voids in it as possible.

Is there an off the shelf algorithm that does this?  How would you approach it in a way that balances speed of calculation with packing quality?

**UPDATE** Detail on packing density: this depends on what volume is chosen for the calculation.  For this, we're looking to pack a certain number of layers of spheres around the fixed ones.  Form a surface of points which are exactly a distance d to the surface of the closest fixed sphere; the packing density should be calculated within the volume enclosed by that surface.  It's convenient if d = some multiple of the size of the packed spheres.  (Assume we can place at least as many free spheres as needed to fill that volume; there may be excess ones, it doesn't matter where they're placed)

The fixed and all the variable spheres are all pretty similar sizes (let's say within 2x range from smallest to largest).  In practice the degree of overlap of the fixed spheres is also limited: no fixed sphere is closer than a certain distance (around 0.2-0.3 diameters) of any other fixed sphere (so it is guaranteed that they are spread out, and/or only overlap a few neighbors rather than all overlapping each other)

Bounty posted!

Comment: I would try (1) Make a crystalline pack of the free spheres in the compact volume (roughly spherical), pretending that the fixed spheres do not exist. (2) Remove the free spheres from the volume occupied by the fixed spheres. (3) You might be able to optimize a bit by tucking-in the free spheres toward the fixed spheres. --- I'm not an expert and don't know anything about the packing or optimization. Interesting problem.

Comment: @norio thanks!  i've seen people do 1&2, but the result tends to leave a void roughly half the size of a free sphere on average around the fixed spheres.  tucking-in is nontrivial :)  i guess something like that could be done by (eg) moving each free sphere (one at a time) in the direction of the nearest fixed sphere until it hits something.  that would leave gaps between free spheres because some of them can't get close enough once others have moved. please feel free to post an answer if you'd like

Comment: @norio i was thinking of going more in the opposite direction, placing free spheres one at a time so they touch as many others as possible (more accurately - so the solid angle subtended by the spheres they are touching is maximized).

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page you cited, the crystalline packing has 0.74 filling ratio while the random close packing has 0.64. According to your problem specification, the number of fixed spheres is 1/10 of the free spheres. Assuming that the radius of the fixed spheres is the same as the free spheres on average, simply voiding the volume of the fixed spheres from the crystalized free spheres will already give as high filling ratio as the random close packing. With the fixed spheres placed, the filling ratio will be higher. .. I guess.

Comment: " the result tends to leave a void roughly half the size of a free sphere on average": if you start from a  cubic close packing, I don't think that you can insert many more spheres in the voids around the fixed ones.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "if you start from a cubic close packing" - indeed, it's hard to do better from that starting point, but there are typically much more efficient irregular packings around the fixed spheres.  consider the case where the fixed sphere diameter is large, and there is only one fixed sphere; an efficient packing is (essentially) something like winding the free spheres like beads on a string around the fixed sphere (related to a tesselation of the fixed sphere), rather than removing the intersecting part of a regular cubic lattice which leaves a gap.

Comment: @AlexI: I don't agree.

Comment: @YvesDaoust with which part? you don't think there is a more efficient packing than cubic in the vicinity of a large fixed sphere?

Comment: I didn't say cubic, did I ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a lattice where each point is equidistant by the diameter of the fill sphere. Any lattice shape, meeting the above definition will suffice.

Orient the translation and rotation of the lattice to minimize the center offsets of the fixed spheres to produce the world transform.

Fixed Pass 1:

Create a list of any lattice points within the fixed spheres radii + the diameter of the fill spheres.
For the latter keep the positional (origin - point) difference vectors in a list.

Flag in the lattice points(removal) in the list.

Lattice Pass 1:

Combine,i.e.  re-base origin to overlap point(either a true overlap or extended to fill radius), any overlapping Fixed sphere's distance vectors. Storing the value on one side and flagging it on the other, to permit multiple overlaps.

This is where a decision is needed:

1. Optimize space over time, Computationally slow:
   Add points from the adjusted origin radius + fill radius. Then iterating over lattice points moving one point at a time away from other points until all  spacing conditions are met. If the lattice points implement spring logic, an optimal solution is produced, given enough iterations(N^2+ N). ?? Stop  Here.... Done.

---

2. Pull the remaining points in lattice to fill the void:
   Warp the lattice near(The size is as large as needed) each overlap point or origin, if no overlap exists pulling the points, to fill the gap.

Lattice Pass 2:

Add missing, i.e. no other point within fill radius + 1, and not near fixed sphere (other radius +  fill radius) flagged points as removed. This should be a small amount of points.

Lattice Pass 3:

Adjust all lattice positions to move closer to the proper grid spacing. This will be monotonically decreasing the distances between points, limited to  >= radius1 + radius2.

Repeat 3-4(or more) times. Applying a tiny amount of randomness(1 to -1 pixel max per dimension) bias offset to the first pass of the created points to avoid any equal spacing conflicts after the warp. If no suitable gap is created the solution may settle to a poorly optimized solution.

Each fill sphere is centered on a lattice grid point.

---

I can see many areas of improvement and optimization, but the point was to provide a clear somewhat fast algorithm that is good, but not guaranteed optimal.

Note the difference between 1 and 2:

Number 1 creates a sphere colliding with other spheres and requires all fills to move multiple times to resolve the collisions.

Number 2 only creates new spheres in empty spaces, and moves the rest inward to adapt, resulting in much faster convergence, since there are no collisions to resolve.